# How to show browser message and on message click event need to handle the code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net page by entering the below mentioned code browser is only showing the message but what if I want to add buttons which I created like --> OK and CANCEL and on OK button I have to write some code:

```
if (isUpdateXMLReportDataSuccess == true)
    {        
        Response.Write(@"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('" + "Bug created successfully." + "')</SCRIPT>");
Response.Redirect("./ManageDefects.aspx");   
    }
    else
    {Response.Write(@"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('" + "Bug not created successfully." + "')</SCRIPT>"); return;}
```

Also here I want to ask that in my case if the `isUpdateXMLReportDataSuccess`  is `true` so according to code browser first should need to showing the message i.e "Bug created successfully." and then it should re-directly Redirect("./ManageDefects.aspx");

But in my case it goes to `Response.Write(@"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('" + "Bug created successfully." + "')</SCRIPT>");` but not showing the message on BROWSER and directly goes to `Response.Redirect("./ManageDefects.aspx");`

It's not showing the browser message.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) please: *The Write method writes a specified string to the current HTTP output.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Instead of
 Response.Write(@"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('" + "Bug created successfully." + "')</SCRIPT>");
Response.Redirect("./ManageDefects.aspx"); 



 Use this 
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "redirect", "alert('message goes here'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "/foldername/pagename.aspx';", true);
```

Comment: If you want message to be displayed before redirect use above code
and if you want ok cancel button only use
confirm("Message goes here!"); instead of alert('message')

Comment: I would do this way too. In fact, I was writing something like that. But you were faster xD

Comment: Hi thanks i my case the above said solution worked.. Thumbs Up. And Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) does not work that way.

When you perform a redirect — `Response.Redirect(path)` — the browser only receive a ["go there" instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) without any page content thus your alert is not displayed.

If you want to display such alert, you have to either display it in the "there" page (in your example, `ManageDefects.aspx`) or do not perform a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (isUpdateXMLReportDataSuccess == true)
        {    
//Here call ScriptManagar 

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Javascript:ShowDetails();", true);    
    }
```

//Javascript Function

```
ShowDetails()
{
$("#yOURdIV").show();
}
```

//HTML

```
     <div id="yOURdIV" class="dialog_content pop-box" style="height: 95px; display: none; position: absolute; left: 30%; top: 65%;">
                    <div class="pop-head">
                        Select Reject Remarks
                    </div>
                    <div class="pop-content" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnoK" runat="server" Text="Confirm"/>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCANCEL" runat="server" Text="Cancel"  />
                    </div>
   </div>


    OnCLick just change `Div` Display  to `Block`

    And ON Click of OK and Cancel write your code //
```

Now Response Redirect and alert you can do it two ways

First :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Request has been on submitted')", true);
                string url = "abc.aspx";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Javascript:alertMesg('" + url + "');", true);
```

call JS :

```
function alertMesg(url )
{
   window.location.href = url;
   win.focus();
}
```

Secondway :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Your Alert Message'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "/Abc.aspx';", true);
```